# Building a framework for release

Tags: ios, xcode

I followed [this](https://github.com/jverkoey/iOS-Framework) tutorial to build a framework but I can't find how to build it for release. The compiler generates two folders `Debug-iphoneos` and `Debug-iphonesimulator` and when I add the framework to another project I get the following linker warnings:

> ld: warning: directory not found for option
>   '-F/Users/fratelli/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Framework-eoohtblqwtxnicgzlmnfspaljsal/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos'
>   ld: warning: directory not found for option
>   '-F/Users/fratelli/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Framework-eoohtblqwtxnicgzlmnfspaljsal/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos'

Does anybody know how to solve this?